# How to use Command for SelectionChanged of Pivot control

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I am using latest version MVVMLight to develop a WP application. I am aware of how to use Command instead of writing code in button click event.

```
<Button Content='Push me' Command='{Binding DisplayMessageCommand}' />
```

However, How do i use the Command for `SelectionChanged` of Pivot control ? 
I don't want to write code in `SelectionChanged` event in code behind .cs file of xaml page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SampleCommand}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```